# Why this global variable is undefined inside a function?

Tags: javascript

Why is this global variable undefined inside a function if the same global variable is re-declared and defined inside that same function?

```
var a = 1;
function testscope(){
 console.log(a, 'inside func');
 //var a=2;
};
testscope();
console.log(a, 'outside func');

output:
1 "inside func"
1 "outside func"
```

Consider same code where var a = 2; inside function block is uncommented

```
var a = 1;
function testscope(){
 console.log(a, 'inside func');
 var a=2; 
};
testscope();
console.log(a, 'outside func');

Output
undefined "inside func"
1 "outside func"
```

Comment: Too many dupetargets...

Comment: Because `var a` is [hoisted](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) to the top of the scope resulting in the start of the function being `var a;`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm framing that comment ;)

Comment: @j08691: 22 characters, two typos. That's not a good ratio. :-) (Fixed.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for finding out. I missed the same question asked earlier. Still voted for the effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because Javascript is not like Java and variable declaration are always pushed up their block. Your second piece of code is strictly equivalent to:

```
var a = 1;
function testscope(){
 var a;  // <-- When executed, the declaration goes up here
 console.log(a, 'inside func');
 a=2;  // <-- and assignation stays there
};
testscope();
console.log(a, 'outside func');

Output
undefined "inside func"
1 "outside func"
```

Comment: Please, blatantly-obvious duplicates need close votes and comments, not answers.

Answer (score -1):

because a on the first function refers to the variable a that exists on the function, while a you write after the variable you write. if you want a global variable accessible inside a function that contains the same variable as the global variable you should add this.a. or if you want to access the variable a in the function you have to write the variable before you call it